# Gradle - Can properties be placed in a settings.gradle.kts

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

Is it possible to place these settings which I currently have in `gradle.properties` in my `settings.gradle.kts` file?

```
org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.caching=true
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible since `gradle.properties` configures the JVM that runs the Gradle build and `settings.gradle.kts` configures the project once the JVM has started and the build starts up. See the [documentation on the build environment](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html)

Answer (score 2):

In my experience you can't do it.

You can check the gradle properties in the [official doc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_configuration_properties).

> The configuration is applied in following order (if an option is configured in multiple locations the last one wins):
>
> - `gradle.properties` in project root directory.
> - `gradle.properties` in GRADLE_USER_HOME directory.
> - system properties, e.g. when `-Dgradle.user.home` is set on the command line.

These properties are used to sep up the environment for your build:

```
org.gradle.caching=(true,false)
org.gradle.caching.debug=(true,false)
org.gradle.configureondemand=(true,false)
org.gradle.console=(auto,plain,rich,verbose)
org.gradle.daemon=(true,false)
org.gradle.daemon.idletimeout=(# of idle millis)
org.gradle.debug=(true,false)
org.gradle.java.home=(path to JDK home)
org.gradle.jvmargs=(JVM arguments)
org.gradle.logging.level=(quiet,warn,lifecycle,info,debug)
org.gradle.parallel=(true,false)
org.gradle.warning.mode=(all,none,summary)
org.gradle.workers.max=(max # of worker processes)
org.gradle.priority=(low,normal)
```

Also you can apply the same rules to `settings.gradle` and `settings.gradle.kts`.[In the documentation](http://Gradle%20defines%20a%20settings%20file.%20The%20settings%20file%20is%20determined%20by%20Gradle%20via%20a%20naming%20convention.%20The%20default%20name%20for%20this%20file%20is%20settings.gradle.%20Later%20in%20this%20chapter%20we%20explain%20how%20Gradle%20looks%20for%20a%20settings%20file.%20%20The%20settings%20file%20is%20executed%20during%20the%20initialization%20phase.):

> Gradle defines a settings file. The settings file is determined by Gradle via a naming convention. The default name for this file is `settings.gradle`.
>   The settings file is executed **during the initialization phase**.

And looking at the `Settings` class in the [API documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.initialization.Settings.html#org.gradle.api.initialization.Settings)

> There is a one-to-one correspondence between a Settings instance and a `settings.gradle` settings file.

You can check the properties that you can initialize with this file.